# get Kafka unconsumed messages count in Java

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

We would like to know the messages count which are not yet consumed and acknowledge by Kafka Consumer for a given Kafka topic.

Is there any way we can get the count of Unconsumed Kafka messages from a given Topic (Topic is having 10 partitions) in Java ??

Answer (score 4):

kafka consumers have a per-partition "records-lag" metric (introduced in [kip-92](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-92+-+Add+per+partition+lag+metrics+to+KafkaConsumer)).
you can sum those metrics for all partitions of your topic, and get a figure for unconsumed messages

Comment: Since the question is tagged with [tag:spring-kafka], I assume it is being used. You can access the metrics with `MessageListenerContainer.metrics()` which returns a map containing the metrics for each consumer, keyed by its `consumer.id`.

Answer (score 2):

There is another alternate approach

Kafka Consumer have API to get endpoint for each partition of a topic

```
List partitions = new ArrayList<>();
        for (PartitionInfo p : parts) {
            partitions.add(new TopicPartition(topic, p.partition()));
        }
Map<TopicPartition, Long> offsets = consumer.endOffsets(partitions);
```

For each topic partition, u can get the latest committed offset.You can easily get the unconsumed lagging by using these 2 numbers

lag=(end of offset-latest committed)

```
for (TopicPartition tp : offsets.keySet()) {
            OffsetAndMetadata commitOffset = consumer.committed(new TopicPartition(tp.topic(), tp.partition()));
            Long lag = commitOffset == null ? offsets.get(tp) : offsets.get(tp) - commitOffset.offset();            
        }
```

Comment: this relies on the consumers in question checkpointing their offsets to kafka (which may not be the case)